# What is shared worker? Different between worker vs shared worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, shared-worker

I had to watch shared worker example. But I can't identify differences between worker vs shared worker. 
Shared worker example https://github.com/mdn/simple-shared-worker.
Can anyone please explain that?

Comment: I already saw that. But my question is different. My doubt is example wise not the concept wise. How shared worker access all scripts of a same domain?

Comment: Hello, my question is duplicated, but the answer is different. As a front end developer, I know this answer. But I can't understand your suggestion, link from stack overflow. Your link has very basic information. So I refer lots of links go through the answer. See my answer in answer tab, then understand it. If you can't understand yourself contact me in this comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Worker and SharedWorker working flow given below.

[image: This image helps to understand working flow and common behavior of Worker and SharedWorker]

[Difference between Worker and SharedWorker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5H9g.png)

Similar features between Worker and Shared Worker.

```
   The Worker works in another thread. So it's not affecting the main thread. So that time users can scroll, view the page without blocking.

1. Worker can't access DOM elements from the web page.
2. Worker can't access global variables and functions from the web page.
3. Worker can't call alert() function.
4. Objects such as window, parent, document can't be accessed inside the worker.
```

Workers own features.

```
Workers life time between page creates and closure. Once the page creates the new workers will be created. View first image that blog diagram says about Wokers.
```

Shared Worker own features.

Shared Worker connects all web pages from same domain. View second image that blog diagram says about Wokers vs Shared Workers.

Reference link, [Workers document](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)